# Partitions in A237981

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, partitions, integer-sequences

- Let $T(n,k)$ be [A237981](https://oeis.org/A237981) i.e. array: row $n$ gives the NW partitions of n; see Comments. Here by $T(n,k)$ I mean $k$-th partition in $n$-th row.
- Let
  $$
  \ell(n) = \left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor
  $$
- Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120) i.e. number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$). Here
  $$
  \operatorname{wt}(2n+1)=\operatorname{wt}(n)+1, \\
  \operatorname{wt}(2n)=\operatorname{wt}(n), \\
  \operatorname{wt}(0)=0
  $$
- Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence such that
  $$
  b(2^k) = 2^k, \\
  f(n) = b(n-2^{\ell(n)}), \\
  b(n) = 2^{\ell(n)+\operatorname{wt}(f(n))}(2f(n)+1)
  $$
- Let $c(n)$ be an increasing integer sequence which contain all values of $b(n)$.
- Let $d(n)$ be a vector with elements equal to run lengths of zeros (each of which is increased by $1$) in the binary expansion of $n$ starting from the right side.

I conjecture that vectors with elements equal to run length of zeros (each of which increased by 1) in the binary expansion of the values of $c(n)$ with a bit length equals to $m$, where the elements are sorted and reversed, correspond to the partitions in the $m$-th row of [A237981](https://oeis.org/A237981).

By the way, I accidentally discovered a convenient algorithm for getting the values of $c(n)$ without using $b(n)$. Here it is:

Start with $c(1) = 1, c(2) = 2$, $e(1) = 1, e(2) = 2$ and $i=2$, $j=2$, $k=0$, $q=2$. After that for $s=3$ up to $s=n$

- check if $i=j$
- if it's true, apply $i:=i+1$, $j:=\left\lfloor\frac{i+1}{2}\right\rfloor+1$, $k:=0$, $q:=q+1$, $c(s)=2^{i-1}$, $e(q)=s$.
- if it's not true, apply $c(s)=c(e(j)+k)+2^{i-1}$ and then check if $\operatorname{wt}(e(j)+k+1)=\left\lfloor\sqrt i\right\rfloor$ or $(i-j+1)\geqslant g(e(j)+k+1)$ where $g(n)=\ell(n)-\ell(n-2^{\ell(n)})$
- if it's true, apply $j:=j+1$, $k:=0$
- if it's not true, apply $k:=k+1$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
b1(n) = my(t); if( n<0, 0, t = 1 + x * O(x^n); polcoeff( sum(k=1, sqrtint(n), t *= x^(2*k - 1) / (1 - x^k) * (1 + x * O(x^(n - k^2))), 1), n)) \\ A003114
b2(n) = my(L = logint(n, 2), A = n); A -= 2^L; L - if(A==0, 1, logint(A, 2))
b3(n) = my(A = n, B, v1); v1 = vector(hammingweight(n), i, 0); for(i = 1, #v1, B = valuation(A, 2); A \= 2 ^ (B + 1); v1[i] = (B + 1)); v1
rows_upto(n) = my(N = sum(i = 1, n, b1(i)), v1, v2); v1 = vector(N, i, if(i < 3, i)); v2 = [1, 2];  my(i = 2, j = 2, k = 0); for(s = 3, N, if(i == j, i++; v1[s] = 2^(i - 1); j = (i + 1) \ 2 + 1; k = 0; v2 = concat(v2, s), my(A = v2[j] + k); v1[s] = v1[A] + 2^(i - 1); my(B = v1[A + 1]); if((hammingweight(B) == sqrtint(i)) || ((i - j + 1) >= b2(B)), j++; k = 0, k++))); v1 = vector(n, i, Vecrev(vecsort(vector(if(i < n, v2[i + 1] - v2[i], N - v2[i] + 1), j, b3(v1[v2[i] + j - 1])))))
v1 = rows_upto(30)
for(i=1, 30, print(v1[i]))
```

Is there a way to prove it?